# How can I get the username of the user who attempts to run a script as another user?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I'm having a user run a script as another user

Suppose my user is **firstUser** and I execute the following command:

```
sudo -u **secondUser** ....
```

Is it possible to somehow get the **name of the user (firstUser)** who attempts to run that command as secondUser **inside the script**?

Comment: Maybe have a look at `/var/log/messages`.  You could try a test to see what the footprint looks like in `messages` when `sudo -u **secondUser**` is run.  You could then write a script to search the `messages` file for the pattern.  You might need to look at `/var/log/secure` too.

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `sudo -u user some_script ...` runs `some_script` as a child of `sudo`.

So, knowing that `$$` is the shell's PID, and `$PPID` a bash-ism for its parent PID, you ought to be able to do something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

PARENT_USER=$( ps -eo user= $PPID )
if [ "$PARENT_USER" != "$( ps -eo user= $$ )" ]; then
  # I'm not the same user as my parent
  ...
fi
```

It is safer to check `ps -eo user= $$` than to rely on `$USER`, as the latter may be overridden by the parent.  Additionally, `ps` is [allowed to interpret its *user* format specifier](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html#tag_20_96_10) as a decimal number rather than a textual username if the name is "too long."